# Blind Random Sort

Tags: code-challenge, random, sorting

Here's a pretty common pattern for sorting algorithms:

```
def sort(l):
    while not is_sorted(l):
         choose indices i, j
         assert i < j
         if l[i] > l[j]:
             l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
```

These algorithms work well because the indices `i` and `j` are chosen carefully, based on the state of the list `l`.

However, what if we couldn't see `l`, and just had to choose blindly? How fast could we sort the list then?

---

Your challenge is to write a function that outputs a random pair of indices, given only the length of `l`. Specifically, you must output two indices, `i, j`, with `0 <= i < j < len(l)`. Your function should work on any length of list, but it will be scored on a list of length 100.

Your score is the mean number of index choices necessary to sort a uniformly randomly shuffled list according to the above pattern, where the indices are chosen according to your function.

I will score submissions, taking the mean number of index choices over 1000 trials on a uniformly randomly shuffled list of length 100 with no repeated entries.

I reserve the right to run less trials if the submission is clearly non-competitive or does not terminate, and I will run more trials to differentiate the top competitors to find a single winner. If multiple top submissions remain within the margin of error at the limit of my computational resources, I will declare the earlier submission the winner, until further computational resources can be brought to bear.

---

Here's an example scoring program, in Python:

```py
import random
def is_sorted(l):
    for x in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[x] > l[x+1]:
            return False
    return True

def score(length, index_chooser):
    steps = 0
    l = list(range(length))
    random.shuffle(l)

    while not is_sorted(l):
        i, j = index_chooser(length)
        assert (i < j)
        if l[i] > l[j]:
            l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
        steps += 1
    return steps
```

---

Your function may not maintain any mutable state, interact with global variables, affect the list `l`, etc. Your function's only input must be the length of the list `l`, and it must output a ordered pair of integers in the range `[0, len(l)-1]` (or appropriate for your language's list indexing). Feel free to ask whether something's allowed in the comments.

Submissions may be in any free-to-use language. Please include a scoring harness if one has not already been posted for your language. You may post a provisional score, but I will leave a comment with the official score.

Scoring is the mean number of steps to a sorted list on a uniformly randomly shuffled list of length 100. Good luck.

Comment: If we can't maintain a mutable state, then is the submission just based on whatever distribution we implement?

Comment: @JoKing Indeed - your submission is a distribution

Comment: Why don't you allow mutable state?  Allowing it means that submissions can better fine-tune their algorithms, as opposed to hoping that the right items get picked.

Comment: @NathanMerrill If mutable state were allowed, the winner would just be a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) which is already a well studied problem.

Comment: Isn't finding efficient sorting networks of a large size a really hard problem?  As long as N > 20, I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: But a random number generator is a mutable state? Am I right?

Comment: @tsh A standard random number generator is allowed, as exception to the mutable state rule. Don't use this to transfer information between iterations.

Comment: @NathanMerrill If you want to post that question, feel free. It's not this question, however.

Comment: @isaacg I wasn't proposing you actually change the challenge, I was asking what your reasoning was :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Oh, sure. The challenge "Design the best sorting network", while an interesting question, has been studied a lot in the CS research world. As a result, the best submissions would probably just consist of implementations of research papers, such as Batcher's bitonic sort. The question I've asked here is original as far as I know, and so should have more room for innovation.

Comment: @Lynn Switched, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Python, score = 4508

```python
def half_life_3(length):
    h = int(random.uniform(1, (length / 2) ** -3 ** -0.5) ** -3 ** 0.5)
    i = random.randrange(length - h)
    return i, i + h
```

Half-Life 3 confirmed.

## Python, score = 11009

```python
def bubble(length):
    i = random.randrange(length - 1)
    return i, i + 1
```

Apparently a randomized bubble sort doesn’t do all that much worse than a normal bubble sort.

## Optimal distributions for small length

There’s no way this could be extended to length 100, but it’s interesting to look at anyway.  I computed optimal distributions for small cases (length ≤ 7) using gradient descent and lots of matrix algebra.  The *k*th column shows the probability of each swap at distance *k*.

```
length=1
score=0.0000

length=2
1.0000
score=0.5000

length=3
0.5000 0.0000
0.5000
score=2.8333

length=4
0.2957 0.0368 0.0000 
0.3351 0.0368 
0.2957 
score=7.5106

length=5
0.2019 0.0396 0.0000 0.0000 
0.2279 0.0613 0.0000 
0.2279 0.0396 
0.2019 
score=14.4544

length=6
0.1499 0.0362 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.1679 0.0558 0.0082 0.0000 
0.1721 0.0558 0.0000 
0.1679 0.0362 
0.1499 
score=23.4838

length=7
0.1168 0.0300 0.0041 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.1313 0.0443 0.0156 0.0000 0.0000 
0.1355 0.0450 0.0155 0.0000 
0.1355 0.0443 0.0041 
0.1313 0.0300 
0.1168 
score=34.4257
```

Comment: Your score: 11009

Comment: Can you explain your half life 3 answer a bit?  Is the point just to bias the random number towards the front of the list?

Comment: The optimal distributions for small length are very interesting - I notice that biasing towards the center is useful, especially for larger swap distance.

Comment: @Max The entire problem is about biasing the random numbers in useful ways; this way happened to be useful. Note that `h` is the distance between the swapped elements; it doesn’t represent the front or the back.

Comment: Your half life score: 4508 on 10000 samples.

Answer (score 7):

## Score: 4627

```python
def rand_step(n):
	step_size = random.choice([1, 1, 4, 16])
	
	if step_size > n - 1:
		step_size = 1 
	
	start = random.randint(0, n - step_size - 1)
	return (start, start + step_size)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLBbsMgDD2Hr/CRqHRLpmmHattX7FZVEWtJQ0YgArJl@/nOJk2bXipFMQb7vecH/W9snH066a53PoKX9uC600HVaVmFqHpu8w3LaFUF/afg7Vz1sG@c3iu@LQXg94z/l13OMpbpGq7l72BhDSVC3GCUQJUhSmS9IFLQNvJCpKZrPQIgsldx8BZ46hIwNa@uZXkSHvbOK26UPcZGgLYHNVYo1QXl50ECUhYsMxiMDpEj73FuyYlokhOaoa4NHuDWT6ONgg8/KJqkdh5GxIZl57ok/IzGN9txh5NjWJW7tJl9eiW/cKVMSBDzNEkP5lpAi3pu9M6S8FgGzCPX8Aot5YlETyTtREG5SCnNhUGkkrPxAVboOmNkkfw@VndsQveHropeSxNopFnp0PF75gK5UpEr42TLAiWHR6iNk3G5yVjv8boXcsoCr/7y8vBFFUWRn/4B)

Outputs random indices whose distance apart is chosen uniformly from `[1,1,4,16]`. The idea is to have a mix of 1-step swaps with swaps at larger scales.

I hand-tweaked these values for lists of length 100, and they are likely far from optimal. Some machine search could probably optimize the distribution over distances for the random-pair-with-chosen-distance strategy.

Comment: Your score: 4627 on 10,000 samples. I'll run it again with more samples if you're among the leaders after a few days.

Answer (score 3):

## Score: 28493

```python
def x_and_y(l):
    x = random.choice(range(l))
    y = random.choice(range(l))
    while y == x and l != 1: y = random.choice(range(l))
    return sorted([x,y])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLLboMwELzzFdtTQHFbUG9R6Vf0FiFEwxJMDEa2UeHr6domiaxUyh78mvHu7GNcTCuHj5X3o1QGVDXUsl9rbGAu6VwusUgOEZDNkG/w26mV/IQx3c5IeOLw5Qn@23KBlpWTK@KBgJccssPTjwrNpAbQpA/r@DizpUicQn2Simg4nE3LwCheCc2ADzXOJXmSGtWmXU89BUnduZEKSmKBj@K/bTzHNTjqG9uaoJvg2lx1uYCbOCfQi9ft1DTC6r4hPudvNeHd/1XDfNfgPb5mSciyxhsQx7mAL7vts@KRYe1HYXUJEBQaH7mPPM6go/SCol0zDIiVJsTEHD6hCxEnkXuJ3T8CLcgcZutIG3NPAc8XfU/zcO8D9YweHBLMwdS/@6ZF0aj4YOId1X/H/DRkacrALdv8Up@i9Q8)

This solution just selects distinct values for `x` and `y` randomly from the range and returns them in sorted order. As far as I can tell, this performs better than choosing `x` then choosing `y` from the remaining values.

Comment: Your score: 28493

Answer (score 3):

## Python, score: 39525

```python
def get_indices(l):
    x = random.choice(range(l-1))
    y = random.choice(range(x+1,l))
    return [x,y]
```

First it chooses a random value in the range \$[0, l-1)\$ for the \$x\$-index.
After that it will choose another random value larger than \$x\$ in the range \$[x+1, l)\$ for the \$y\$-index.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZLPboMwDMbvPIVvBZFtoN6qdS@x3SpUsdZA2pSgJGj06Znzh1HG5gOQfD/sL3a6u2lkux35rZPKgCrbs7yNZ6ygRnPk7ZmfUMci2UVAMcA@IM@nRpIU06rGWDzlSeKI@z/EkOZMBEah6VULh4HdC1dKn6SiJNjWpmFgFC@FZkDFcThSFqlRBQO6v1GBzH1XUsGRKPAV/G@Bc6zBTv/QNgStBNdmcu0KBlPOmDeum76qBOmz8tVwgfChepzzTx6G2YPPSM1YUjZ4BeIwFPBmX2lerAkbnwrL60JBoXHNrjnO4ELHWzRtOuECLDUpJubwCpel4ixyb/Hyh0ErMqfZPtKLua0F55ue7iGf50Azow2nPM6f9l/80KLo1yy3oYGd4q2JN@/2fuxgw8JNybOMgXs8XNIkGb8B)

Comment: Your score: 39525

Answer (score 2):

## Python, score ≈ 5000

```py
def exponentialDistance(n):
    epsilon = 0.25
    for dist in range(1, n):
        if random.random() < epsilon:
            break
    else:
        dist = 1
    low = random.randrange(0, n - dist)
    high = low + dist
    return low, high
```

Tried with a bunch of epsilon values, 0.25 seems to be the best.

#### Score ≈ 8881

```py
def segmentedShuffle(n):
    segments = 20
    segmentLength = (n - 1) // segments + 1

    if random.random() < 0.75:
        a = b = 0
        while a == b or a >= n or b >= n:
            segment = random.randrange(segments)
            a = random.randrange(segmentLength) + segment * segmentLength
            b = random.randrange(segmentLength) + segment * segmentLength
        return sorted([a, b])

    highSegment = random.randrange(1, segments)
    return highSegment * segmentLength - 1, highSegment * segmentLength
```

A different approach.  Not as good, and it dies horribly with length not divisible by the number of segments, but still fun to build.

Comment: Your scores: Exponential distance: 5055. Segmented shuffle: 8901

Answer (score 1):

## Score: 4583

```
def rand_shell(l):
    steps = [1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, 129]
    candidates = [(left, left + step)
            for (step, nstep) in zip(steps, steps[1:])
            for left in range(0, l - step)
            for i in range(nstep // step)
    ]
    return random.choice(candidates)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPtjtowEPyfp1jpdLqk@I44gRDQXaV7hbb/EEIpOMQ0JJFjrrQvT3dtkwCtUksk7HhmP8ZO80sXdRWdz/LQ1EqDyqptffC8rcih3dRK@KWodrpgIKutOK03RV23QgULD3C1WjQtvEFoohL/lbLVPibZXYRBYPZs3pe2OOZ5iXsW/VnIUsA3dRQ2H628VnDCanCd5ZkHPYOWzKFcnlbwmV4jvrrdpfVdiexHh4qyFbccJfRRVXaEbkMy2OMUN7NeBulIWYuo9iW8wr5HTUfSdrS/64c2mMHJInwxA3Uc6@PoDbh1ntxat4Uoy/VOVEJlula@ITkbbkloZ19vg7DcZlrQwSyx@VxjNXzCyNQJ/nKKHDfZGVSGQe7/lo2tyGx3S75Y/VtqcnfnFWIxeB6oJHuuqQbj8R2798Wdkbs8eB5yI/x@QHe1epK14@r2fhGNyLSv5UHgIKWbxbnVKFlp/@krQQt4bJ/g0e3by00JjInuQ2BD5xLcD2dqBqubSiZjV8pEwTXh/QNz7sSF4fOXED5Bezz4jgxjsHkDz7sekKPtPMTHkjOIGUwZzBGZYYBRgiGP5qsAHuA9TOOYp94DDOlRyFEUY5TEJJ5ZMU/SJJwMiSOjn6COQWq7QIhjxDGMcCOiroiG2ASxKZHxN0MsxQxz4oap6zaMp2kyVBCVnCoSFvFONUmi/88YcdsC55ETxsk0mQ8JaQgSkzrlV6rBcnQAaMWEE3Y5iDhOosjzzuc/)

I've no idea why. I just tried sequences listed on wikipedia artical for [shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort). And this one seem works best. It get similar score with [the one xnor posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174166/44718).

Comment: Your score: 4583 on 10,000 samples. I'll run it again with more samples if you're among the leaders in a few days.

Comment: Also, I'm running a faster program that samples the same distribution, so I can get more samples.

Comment: @isaacg For better testing performance, moving `candidates` out of the function as a global variable should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's much faster than what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 4871

```python
import random
def index_chooser(length):
    e= random.choice([int(length/i) for i in range(4,length*3/4)])
    s =random.choice(range(length-e))
    return [s,s+e]
def score(length, index_chooser):
    steps = 0
    l = list(range(length))
    random.shuffle(l)
    while True:
        for x in range(length-1):
            if l[x] > l[x+1]:
                break
        else:
            return steps
        i, j = index_chooser(length)
        assert(i < j)
        if l[i] > l[j]:
            l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
        steps += 1

print sum([score(100, index_chooser) for t in range(100)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBToQwEIbvPMUcwa0u6J6M@BTeCDEIw1IsLWlLxKfHactC2DgX4P@/DP/MjL@2U/J5WfgwKm1BV7JRQ9RgC1w2OH/WnVIGdSxQXm2XvEZAhfkKPpHNa4wLLu2KnHkCrdLAqYGjrhhfWLAeXs6XpEx8CwP5sUVAA/iISaA02klLKAwzJyx9LFMrfePYMeSazlgcqT2k/kvQm@DGHn5wax8SmG5qW0FeUH86LhA@9IShnys30bxPtMbMkp1wxVsQxVzCu3ucsvLouvrSWH1vKgqDR2Yd2I@wGZxBT1P8e5ANqgypNubwBv2u@kQ8JOrv8jiDed2tiB7MSxsT9njKIYuiUdOFwUxDXIQDZGl6v32/JLsviRC69rL8AQ)

Comment: Your score: 4871 on 10000 samples